# Scoping variables in a class

Tags: java, class, variables, scope

In a method, we can create a scope, to limit the access to some variables.

```
void func() {
    {
        int num = 3;
    }
    // num is not accessible here
}
```

In a class, how can we create a scope (or structure alike), such that certain fields are only accessible by certain methods?

```
class MyClass {
    private String myHeart = "pure";
    void method_friendly {
        // should able to access myHeart
    }

    // ---------- methods under this line should not access myHeart

    void method_evil {
        // please don't touch myHeart
    }
}
```

Comment: A question. In which situation, something like that is useful?

Comment: This really calls for decomposition into more classes, with private fields. Inner classes won't do it.

Comment: @Christian, i know this might not be a good design. But i sometimes run into a situation like this. For example, some fields are critical to the integrity of the structure. i want only certain methods to be able to alter them. For the reason (1) clearer for myself to maintenance, and (2) other methods, after overridden by sub-classes, may break the integrity of it.

Comment: @SeanOwen, `myHeart` could be said more "private" than a private field. i don't want to create another class, such that i have to expose it somehow, as a class can only be public or /*package*/. i am thinking about doing inner-class. Why would you say that's not possible?

Comment: @SeanOwen, i did a few trials. i guess why inner-class won't work because (1) if inner-class has not been initialised, outer-class cannot access it, (2) if inner-class has been initialised, outer-class can even access its private members.

Comment: I mean that `private` fields of inner classes are still visible to the enclosing class.

Comment: @SeanOwen, Thanks Sean. Yup, i just noticed it after my trials. i thought a non-static inner-class, which is said associated with an instance of the enclosing class, does not need to be instantiated, and act as an "inner scope" which hide private field. i feel this would be more intuitive. But Java doesn't behave like this. (P.S. in my previous comment, i meant "instantiated" not "initialised", sorry)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is make a base class with the methods you want everything to be able to use and then make derived classes that would be able to use those and some special methods.

Comment: Do you mean having base class, and extended sub-class? I have tried by putting those two classes in one file, having the file named "SubClass.java". This have some problems, as I could not make SuperClass private. In case a method in SuperClass has to return `this`. It can cause ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

You could write one abstract class and declare the methods you deem to be important and should be able to access certain fields. You would declare your variables `private`.You could then write any subclass and those classes wouldn't be able to alter the original fields without a mutatter method.